# Full distribution of FPTs in random walks on graphs

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-graphs, statistical-physics

There is a lot of published research on the mean passage passage time (FPT) for random walks on various types of graphs. How about the *variance* of the FPT and higher momenta? In fact, I would be interested to know for what graphs and random graphs the full distribution of FPTs has been computed analytically in some regime.

For elementary graphs like $K_n$, the full distribution of the FPT is a back-of-the-envelope calculation. For the Erdős–Rényi model in the sparse regime, the full distribution of FPTs has been computed 
in cond-mat/0410309. I have found other papers about the Erdős–Rényi -- but nothing, for instance, about the FTP distribution in the Barabasi model, or scale-free networks in general.

Perhaps I'm not searching efficiently? If somebody could redirect me, I would be grateful. I'm virtually new to this website, so I can only hope the question is not off-topic.